# Rails Array not Saving to DB

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table with check boxes in the first column and a list of plan names in another column. I want to be able to check the boxes next to the listings, click a form_submit button, and have those checked listings save as an array to a column in my database.

I have the table functioning with an array column - I can manually enter an array into the column (using a db management service called Adminium). However as soon as I try to update the array values through the application, it clears the array values and doesn't add the selected items.

**View**

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'planselection', :id => @current_plan.id, :method => :put  do %>

<%= submit_tag "Add Selected Plans to Quote" %> 

 <table id="DT" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
            <th>Plan name</th>
      <th>Carrier</th>
      <th>Plan type</th>
      <th>Deductible</th>
      <th>Monthly Premium</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @benefit_details.where(:plan_year => @current_plan.plan_year).each do |benefit_detail| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "plan_selection[]", benefit_detail.plan_name %></td>
        <td><%= benefit_detail.plan_name %></td> 
        <td><%= benefit_detail.carrier %></td>
        <td><%= benefit_detail.plan_type %></td>
                <td><%= benefit_detail.deductible %></td>
                <td><% @AgeTest = AgeFactor.where("carrier = ? AND age = ?", @Carrier, @Age).pluck(:age_factor) %></td>

                <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-xs ">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-xs ">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-xs ">
                        <i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
                </td>


      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table> 
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
  def planselection
    # TODO Add all plan selections to Current plan

    @current_plan.update(plan_selection: "plan_selection")
    #@current_plan.update("plan_selection=?", :planselection)

    redirect_to :back
  end
```

**Terminal Output**

```
Started POST "/current_plans/planselection?id=12&method=put" for 66.186.164.130 at 2015-07-01 17:46:32 +0000
Processing by CurrentPlansController#planselection as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aEwaOrQwzbSKkeLbdyJ3=", "commit"=>"Add Selected Plans to Quote", "DT_length"=>"10", "plan_selection"=>["Silver HMO 2,000 - MD3487/RX1028", "Silver HMO 2,000 - MD3487/RX1022", "Silver HMO 2,500 - MD3486/RX1021", "Silver HMO 2,500 - MD3486/RX1022"], "id"=>"12", "method"=>"put"}
  CurrentPlan Load (30.5ms)  SELECT  "current_plans".* FROM "current_plans"  WHERE "current_plans"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
   (30.5ms)  BEGIN
   (30.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Try this -> @current_plan.update(plan_selection: params[:plan_selection])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -> @current_plan.update(plan_selection: params[:plan_selection])